# "pip" and "python" commands not found, but python3 and pip3 work fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Just started working my way through [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://python-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref) and having some trouble setting up pip and virtual environments.

I've noticed that I've had to use "python3" and "pip3" in place of "python" and "pip" (neither of the latter commands are found) but I've read that these commands should be able to be used interchangeably?

This seems to create an issue later on when setting paths for virtualenvwrapper, forcing me to deviate from the tutorial and get lost in Google search results.

How can I "find" the python and pip commands?

Comment: They should be in your PATH, as in system environment parameters

Comment: also look at `which python` and `which pip` from a shell to locate the actual executables being used (or `which python3`, `which pip3`, depending on what you want to know the location of)

Answer (score 2):

You will find a fairly carefully thought out answer in [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). The gist is that the `python` command on the `PATH` should point to `python2`, not `python3`, by default. If a system does not have `python2`, it could be that it doesn't have `python`, but only `python3`.

It is perfectly acceptable for users and sysadmins to override this. I suspect your local system has a convenience tool for you to set the default invocation of `python`.

Comment: When search for "python" in Synaptic Package Manager, I do see that Python 2.7 is installed. I just tried "python2" and that did work, so it looks like I just don't have "python" binded to anything...

Comment: @Stn https://askubuntu.com/a/460578/27272 may help as well. There's some explanation of Ubuntu plans to encourage people to use python3, as well as a suggestion to use `sudo update-alternatives --config python`